# How to make my Windows software run on Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a host of engine simulation softwares made by private factory racing team engineers but it is designed to work only on Windows but I want to make it work on Linux, how can I do so?.

Comment: Wouldn't it actually be better if you ask the people who made the software if they have plans or can make it work on Linux? being so secretive as you make it sound I doubt WINE offers any kind of compatibility for it.

Answer (score 0):

If Wine doesn't work, try a VM, like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)